# How to create a database in TablePlus

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm using TablePlus (https://tableplus.io/) and couldn't find a way to create a new database directly within the app? Is there a way to do that or I have to create a database from outside?

Comment: What happens when you run [`create database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html)?  And are you sure you want a new _database_ rather than a table?

Comment: can you share more information regarding postgresql version and how you'e trying to create the database? Connecting to the maintenance database and performing a CREATE DATABASE would certainly do (in case you have the right permissions)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's really not obvious in the software!

Answer (score 2):

Press Cmd + K to list all databases, then hit **+** to create a new database.

Comment: There is no "+" in the Windows version